How to find an orbit around an irregular 2-D shape
Sorry for my lack of math vocabulary. I use the word "orbit" loosely because I don't know what else to call it.
If I wanted to find the orbit around a circle I could easily just scale it by n-times and I could say that 1.2x the radius is the orbit. Where we have some equidistant value from the original circle to the orbit circle all the way around.
For irregular or asymmetrical shapes I can scale any shape using pythagorean, sin, cos, etc. I originally thought this was the way to go. However, to my dismay, this does not produce an "orbit" as inflections in the asymmetry of the shape, or concavities won't align and the "orbit" will cross into the original shape, which is not what I want. (see figure below)
example image of scale vs orbit for irregular shape
What I want to do is given a set of discrete coordinates along the perimeter of a shape I want to be able to derive a formula to find a corresponding orbit coordinate. Similar to the way I am able to find a scaled coordinate.
I've been thinking about this a while and I'm almost resigned to believe that there isn't a straightforward way to do this. Anyway I am hoping someone who studies the math of shapes could let me know. Thanks!
It'd be useful for things like for example given a perimeter I wanted to program a camera or sentry to orbit without having it crash into the perimeter but not deviate too far from said perimeter either.

It seems you are looking for parallel curves of the boundary curve of a shape. Look at wiki for more info.

Another keyword : dilation (of shapes) in the framework of the domain called "mathematical morphology".

Still another keyword : offset curves (or parallel curves). See here.

Thanks guy! I kind of thought there was a name for what I was looking for. It seems from reading the material there isn't a straightforward way to map the initial coordinate to a parallel curve coordinate, or dilated coordinate (unless I know the function of the shape which I don't). It seems I'd basically have to create a new shape given the tools above and then remap that new shape which is doable. Just not as easy as I had been trying to imagine. Thanks again!
